# I'm seeing big dissimilarities in the tensorboard scalar plots when changing the X-axis from step to relative (see images). Want to know why?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorboard

Referring to the two images posted below from the same RL simulation;
The tensorboard scalar plot for the loss with the horizontal axis set to 'step' looks rather all over the place.

[image: Loss with the horizontal axis set to 'step']

The second scalar plot with the horizontal axis set to 'relative' shows the loss going down over time.

[image: Loss with the horizontal axis set to 'relative']

I'm trying to understand whether this is a bug in tensorboard or there is actually some debugging insight that I can get from this observation. Appreciate it if you could share your thoughts on these observations and maybe some of your personal experience related to similar observations. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You probably wrote several training sessions on the same log file. As a result, you get several datapoints for the same step, and a messed up  plot.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Indeed I checked the possibility of multiple sessions in the same log file. But even after deleting all previous logs and running the simulation fresh, still results in similar observations. Anyway to clarify my understanding of a session: when we run RL, we have a training loop that runs until convergence or some max number of episodes. So according to TF perspective, is each iteration a separate session or can we say the entire run until the end of the training loop is one session?

Comment: It depends on how you write your code.

Comment: Ok, so this is a good point that I need to explore a bit more then. I was assuming the entire simulation to be a single session, but maybe TF thinks differently. Could you please suggest some material that I could refer to in order to clarify these differences in coding styles?